# Thumb image from server url

Tags: ios, swift

How to create thumb image from video URL and load in table view cell

I am using this code but it freezes table view

```
 func generateThumbImage(url : NSURL) -> UIImage{
    var asset : AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset
    var assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    var error       : NSError? = nil
    var time        : CMTime = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    var img         : CGImageRef = assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil, error: &error)
    var frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)!

    return frameImg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try that code may help to you

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class CommonFunctions {

    static let shared = CommonFunctions()

    typealias ResponseBlock = (_ result: UIImage?) -> Void

    func getVideoThumnail(URLString: String, responseBlock:@escaping ResponseBlock) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let url = URL(string: URLString)
            let asset = AVAsset(url: url!)
            let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let time = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 2)
            let img = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            if img != nil {
                let frameImg  = UIImage(cgImage: img!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    responseBlock(frameImg)
                })
            }else {
                responseBlock(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

use :-

```
 CommonFunctions.shared.getVideoThumnail(URLString: downloadURL) { (image) in
                                if image != nil {
                                      let thumbimage = image
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: same code used, freezing stopped but now prob is that collection cell replaced each other while scrolling

Comment: same code used, freezing stopped but now prob is that collection cell replaced each other while scrolling, I have image and video both I have to show these in horizontal collection cell inside vertical table view.

Comment: @PramodShukla sorry not understand mean by collection cell replace?

Comment: image interchange across cell while scrolling collection view

Comment: @PramodShukla you can give tag of cell? and where to load image in cell..

Answer (score 0):

Use your method in `UIThread`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    // your UI update code
}
```

It prevents from freezing.